# Get Posted XML from HttpServletRequest Object

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a Filter that receives the HttpServletRequest and the request is a POST that consists of an xml that I need to read into my filter method.  What is the best way to get the posted xml from the HttpServletRequest object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how the client has sent it.

If it's been sent as the raw request body, then use [`ServletRequest#getInputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getInputStream--):

```
InputStream xml = request.getInputStream();
// ...
```

If it's been sent as a regular `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request parameter, then use [`ServletRequest#getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter-java.lang.String-):

```
String xml = request.getParameter("somename");
// ...
```

If it's been sent as an uploaded file in flavor of a `multipart/form-data` part, then use [`HttpServletRequest#getPart()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart-java.lang.String-).

```
InputStream xml = request.getPart("somename").getInputStream();
// ...
```

That were the ways supported by the standard servlet API. Other ways may require a different or 3rd party API (e.g. SOAP).