# How to create a servlet that receives a XML based request and sends a XML in the response in JAVA using IDEA IDE

Tags: java, servlets

I am a novice in Servlet and I need to create a Servlet that receive a XML based request and send response in XML using Java.

I have created a simple Hello world program using servlet to understand the basics,and have also googled to find a proper tutorial for creating a servlet that request and respond in XML, but could not find any proper related solutions.

Therefore, please if any one who could lead me with a simple example like how should I proceed to create a servlet that request and respond in XML using Java will be really helpful any link that helps in understanding the same would also be appreciated.

(I am using IntelliJ IDEA as a IDE)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very generic question... anyway:

For the request part, you can follow this: [Get Posted XML from HttpServletRequest Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453649/get-posted-xml-from-httpservletrequest-object)

For the response, you simply do this:

```
response.setContentType("text/xml");
```

and then attach the OutputStream to your xml in some way.

For example, follow this example:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/AnotherservlettoSendXML.htm

Comment: Thank you Paolof76! I am totally new to the topic therefore needed a very generic answer so that I could proceed and then deploy my problem in it. Your response really helped a lot. Thanks!